# Easy way to alter mvc 4 project to include Form Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I created an MVC project using the Intranet Template (Integrated Authentication)

Now i realize i really need the Internet Template. (Forms authentication)

Is there an easy way to transform my project?

A magical Nuget?!?

Comment: using asp.net-mvc for quite a time now, I have no idea what you are asking...

Comment: are you with me or still against me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change your web.config to use forms authentication.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/SignIn" requireSSL="true" protection="All" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

As of the controller logic, I would create another project and just copy the views and controller code from there to your current project.